# mongo update using arrayFilters and identifier results in "cannot use the part to traverse the element"

Tags: mongodb

Following the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#positional-update-arrayfilters), I am trying to update if a condition is met and I get the above error. I have an array of objects, and if the condition is met, I want to update a specific field of the nested object. Here is what I have so far:

**Example doc**

```
"userImages" : [
    {
        "profilePicture" : "https://myprofilepic.jpg"
    },
    {
        "favoritePicture" : "https://myfavepic.jpg"
    }
 ]
```

**Code**

```
const imageToChange = 'https://noLongerValidImage';

const query = { _id };

const updateQuery = { 
  '$set': { 
    'userImages.$[elem].profilePicture': 'https://newProfilePic.png' 
  } 
};

const options = {
  "multi":false,
  "upsert":false,
  "arrayFilters":[{
    "elem.profilePicture":imageToChange
  }]
}
```

I dont see anything wrong, which is troublesome in itself as I cannot get around this:

> cannot use the part (userImages of userImages.$[elem].profilePicture)
>   to traverse the element ({userImages: [ { profilePicture:
>   "https://myprofilepic.jpg", favoritePicture:
>   "https://myprofilepic.jpg" }

Here is the query being run:

```
db.collection.update(
   query,
   updateQuery,
   options
)
```

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using? can you the full query?

Comment: @Saravana 3.4.10

Comment: Can you post the complete query you're trying?

Comment: @Saravana sorry for the delay, I have updated the post with the query being run.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:

1. Are you sure this version of MongoDB supports the filtered positional operator? [This page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) suggests that you need 3.6
2. What's the value of `featureCompatibilityVersion` variable?

   ```
   > db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
   { "featureCompatibilityVersion" : { "version" : "3.4" }, "ok" : 1 }`
   ```

In order to set it run:

```
    > db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" })
```

Incompatibilities between versions are described here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/